# Azure durable functions and synchronous read?

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to use Azure Durable Functions to implement a minimal server that accepts data via a POST and returns the same data via a GET - but I don't seem able to generate the GET response.
Is it simply not possible to return the response via a simple GET response?  What I do NOT want to happen is:

1. GET issued
2. GET response returns with second URL
3. Client has to use second URL to get result.

I just want:

1. GET issues
2. GET response with requested data.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure whether durable functions are meant to be used as a 'server'. Durable functions are part of 'serverless' and therefore I'm not sure whether it's possible (in a clean way).

To my knowledge durable functions are used to orchestrate long lasting processes. So for example handling the orchestration of a batch job. Using durable functions it's possible to create an 'Async HTTP API', to check upon the status of the processing a batch of items ([durable function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#async-http)). I've wrote a [blogpost](https://www.luminis.eu/blog/azure-functions-for-your-long-lasting-logic/) about durable functions, feel free to read it (https://www.luminis.eu/blog/azure-functions-for-your-long-lasting-logic/).

But as for your use case; I think you can create two separate Azure functions. One for posting your data, you can use an Azure Blob Storage [output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob). Your second function can have a GET http trigger and depending on your data you can use an blob input binding. No need to use durable functions for it :)!

Not really a direct answer to your question, but hopefully a solution to your problem!